# resize android videoview to fit screen

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to paly video in full screen.
and i set xml like this

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

it works fine in android 4.1, but do not work in android 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean hide the status bar at the same time? Add the following line before `setContentView`.

Further more, custom a view, extends from VideoView, and override the `onMeasure()` to full screen size.

Comment: thank you.I have tried override `protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
     DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

  int screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
  int screenHeight = dm.heightPixels;
  setMeasuredDimension(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    }` and it do not work on 4.2 too